# Symfony form : old values are displayed after saving

Tags: php, forms, symfony1

I have a symfony form with many checkboxes :

```
    $this->form = new SocialSettingsForm($user);

    if ($request->isMethod(sfRequest::POST)) {
      $this->form->bind($request->getParameter('social'));
      if ($this->form->isValid()) {
        $this->form->save();
        $this->success = true;
      }
    }
```

The problem is the following : after saving the form, the checkboxes act weirdly

If the user checked one, it appears checked after the save (normal behaviour)
But if the user unchecked one, it will still appear checked after the save.

I did a var_dump on the form values, unchecked checkboxes have a NULL value, so i don't 
understand why they are still checked.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This seems to be a symfony bug : http://www.devexp.eu/2009/04/23/sfwidgetforminputcheckbox-unchecked-bug/

Comment: It turns out symfony does not reset the 'checked' attribute of checkboxes when binding, so a checkbox will never be considered as unchecked after a bind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use boolean / integer field for saving the checkbox value, use sfValidatorBoolean for your checkboxes. It also converts the input value to a valid boolean. So null will be converted to 0 and will be saved in the database.

***Update with workaround***

In older versions where this do not work, you can add hidden input with the same name as the checkbox and value of 0, before the checkbox. If the checkbox is not checked, the hidden input value will be sent, otherwise the checkbox value will be sent.

Comment: can you post the updated form, as the sfValidatorBoolean is the way to do this (I found 3 more questions on StackOverflow about the checkbox with the same answer... and I'm using it as well). Also specify the symfony version, just in case :)

Comment: Well here it is : https://gist.github.com/a3fe12c22b17735fbb7f i guess i'm just doing something wrong.

Comment: this is usually done in configure, not in setup, but assuming that the parent's setup is empty (e.g. you didn't modify sf code), it's ok. But show the boolean validator code. Are you setting required to false? What's exactly happening when you are using the validator?

Comment: I updated the code here : https://gist.github.com/a3fe12c22b17735fbb7f 
When i use sfValidatorBoolean nothing changes from the behavior i described firstly, the unchecked checkboxes stay checked after the POST

Comment: @Intrepidd what version of Symfony? It seems that it does not work in 1.2, it does it 1.4

Comment: It was 1.4. Anyway i must have done something wrong so i'll accept your answer, it may help other people having this issue.